# SQL Update sequence data based upon date field

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am attempting to update a table that contains deed information.  Specifically property ID, sale sequence, and deed date.  The program generates the sale sequence data sequentially regardless of the deed date or prior deed information for the property in question.

```
[property_ID]   [sale_number]   [sale_deed_date]  
      1               1            01/15/1990  
      1               2            06/25/1970  
      1               3            08/12/1930
```

What I would like to accomplish is re-sequence sale_number data so they are in chronological order. Similar to this:

```
[property_ID]   [sale_number]   [sale_deed_date]  
      1                1             08/12/1930  
      1                2             06/25/1970  
      1                3             01/15/1990
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grabbing the correct order in a cte:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT property_ID, sales_number, sales_deed_date, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Property_ID ORDER BY sales_deed_date) FROM tablename)

UPDATE t
SET t.sales_number = cte.rn
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN cte ON t.property_ID = cte.property_ID AND t.sales_deed_date = cte.sales_deed_date
```